# May's infinite loop machine for Friedlander's result for Adams conjecture

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy

Eric M. Friedlander in the paper [The infinite loop Adams conjecture via Classification Theorem for $\Gamma$-spaces](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2081684) proved the infinite loop Adams conjecture using techniques involved $\Gamma$-space.

I am wondering if this proof has been worked out explicitly using language of $E_{\infty}$ operads. If so, is there a reference for it?